# Calculate total sales for all sales order whose sales order is same as beverages

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get a query for calculating total sales for sales order number that is equal to sales order number for beverages.

Here is my query but it only gives me beverages total sales and not all other items having same sales order:

```
SELECT
SalesOrderNumber,TransactionDate,[ProductClass],[ProductName],  Nett
FROM ((([Sales]
inner join [Date]
on [Sales].DateKey = [Date].DateKey)
inner join [Product] on [Sales].ProductKey = [Product].ProductKey
inner join [ProductCategory] on [Product].ProductCategoryKey =[ProductCategory].ProductCategoryKey)
inner join [Store] on [Sales].StoreKey = [Store].StoreKey)
where  SalesOrderNumber in (select SalesOrderNumber from [Sales] where ProductClass = 'Beverages')
and StoreName = 'XYZ'
and [FullDate] = '2016-04-27'
ORDER BY SalesOrderNumber,TransactionDate
```

Could someone please help me with the above?

Example;

```
Salesorder1: Beverages - 5$
             Chicken - 10$
Salesorder2: Chicken - 12$
             Chips - 8$
```

I just need sum of total which has beverages in it. So, as per above examples, I should get `(Beverages + Chicken = 15$)` and it should not include the `salesorder2`.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is pretty much unreadable. Consider using some intending in the future.

But, since you want a row that contains sum of multiple products, you can't select stuff like [ProductClass] and [ProductName] on the same row. You'll have to GROUP them to something common like SalesOrderNumber.

Not sure at all if below query works, but only things I changed were the first and the last line of your query.

```
SELECT SalesOrderNumber,TransactionDate, SUM(Nett) as sum
FROM 
(
  (
    ([Sales] inner join [Date] on [Sales].DateKey = [Date].DateKey)
  inner join [Product] on [Sales].ProductKey = [Product].ProductKey
  inner join [ProductCategory] on [Product].ProductCategoryKey = [ProductCategory].ProductCategoryKey
  )
inner join [Store] on [Sales].StoreKey = [Store].StoreKey
) 
where SalesOrderNumber in 
  (select SalesOrderNumber from [Sales] where ProductClass = 'Beverages') 
  and StoreName = 'XYZ'
  and [FullDate] = '2016-04-27'
GROUP BY SalesOrderNumber, TransactionDate
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I am new to this so unknown about formatting part but will take care of this next time. Moreover, the query you wrote is not giving me the results I want. But anyways thanks for trying!

Comment: @Shivang: Here's little something I made for you. Not 100% the same case but might help you solve yours: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMd3d4SHJhajRoUTg